# How do I download all SharePoint 2010 Language Packs using Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, internationalization

I would really like to be able to download all SharePoint 2010 Language Packs easily using a powershell script.

Downloading the SharePoint Language Packs will enable automated and scripted SharePoint installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script I put together based on [this script](http://www.sharepointroundtable.com/blogs/rdennis/archive/2011/06/09/download-all-sharepoint-2010-language-packs-using-powershell.aspx) by Ryan Dennis:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
## Prompt for the destination path
$DestPath = Read-Host -Prompt "- Enter the destination path for downloaded files"
## Check that the path entered is valid
If (Test-Path "$DestPath" -Verbose)
{
    ## If destination path is valid, create folder if it doesn't already exist
    $DestFolder = "$DestPath\LanguagePacks"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory $DestFolder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
Else
{
    Write-Warning " - Destination path appears to be invalid."
    ## Pause
    Write-Host " - Please check the path, and try running the script again."
    Write-Host "- Press any key to exit..."
    $null = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    break
}
## We use the hard-coded URL below, so that we can extract the filename (and use it to get destination filename $DestFileName)
## Note: These URLs are subject to change at Microsoft's discretion.
$UrlList = @{
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/C/A6C2FAE9-58A4-410D-81E0-682E8CBF3D18/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "ar"; #Arabic
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/D/B/0DB91457-43D2-4BCC-A7AF-8559C3E3E1CF/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "eu"; #Basque
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/1/C/91CFFA84-3A8C-4B2B-BD1F-AF77073C832D/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "bg"; #Bulgarian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/7/B/07B06744-859A-40CF-84BB-4C8113F9FB75/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "ca"; #Catalan
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/F/C/DFCC90EE-FC55-4EC3-8618-7A2ED0B6F20F/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "zh"; #Chinese Simplified
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/D/E/5DE5B04D-DA7E-41DD-8BB5-FE7BF02630B8/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "zh-ch"; #Chinese Traditional
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/6/B/B6B2439C-EB60-4361-AB83-71CB6B890ADE/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "hr"; #Croatian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/B/6/7B67B8FC-81C6-446A-9681-897C0888D592/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "cs"; #Czech
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/7/CD76DD3E-95E4-4504-93CF-F7CD6D8B7CF5/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "cs"; #Danish
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/8/C/D8C7212B-6DFE-439D-B7D6-EFB35D66041E/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "nl-nl"; #Dutch
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/7/F/17F6BB3B-662F-4555-9760-DB44D3B3F6A4/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "en-us"; #English
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/4/6/446DDD4D-DC67-4663-B7C5-CCFA79316703/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "et"; #Estonian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/6/116C7960-6DFB-468E-BBCB-15E8706783F3/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "fi"; #Finnish
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/0/B/80B8DB8F-D863-4DD9-98E0-A3698510EF13/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "fr-fr"; #French
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/0/F/D0FE84CB-B591-4D5E-9406-CBA2476D4A94/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "gl"; #Galician
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/8/738597D9-2817-46D7-8F70-7FBBEE73ABCF/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "de-de"; #German
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/F/0/5F03CC80-D10A-43D5-AA1D-E84C6C077E2C/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "el"; #Greek
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/1/0/D10A5EC6-6C6B-4C4B-9FF1-A662B397E850/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "he"; #Hebrew
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/5/795A36AA-D414-4D67-A84D-6815D2FB5A88/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "hi"; #Hindi
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/D/B/FDB09771-D7FF-4123-A66D-2F0A58687E90/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "hu"; #Hungarian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/8/4/A843E91B-7AEE-47B4-A144-49F525DEBD9D/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "it-it"; #Italian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/4/D/94DDA001-2059-4F02-8810-8662C1098F8D/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "ja"; #Japanese
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/D/FCD57DCD-2BFB-4638-94A3-583AD688CB4D/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "kk"; #Kazakh
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/D/B9DB186A-8126-49A9-AFA8-C6D63F12AA40/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "ko"; #Korean
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/E/D/3EDD2930-7BEC-4490-B917-7A49CBA7C5E5/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "lv"; #Latvian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/E/E/EEE0F34F-94D1-4202-B0D0-213C93E20536/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "lt"; #Lithuanian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/5/9/D596FB84-8ED3-44A4-88D1-FDD4798E226A/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "no-no"; #Norwegian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/F/1/BF1F45F4-44A8-453D-882D-03BAC1F6A0B5/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "pl"; #Polish
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/9/F/69F59A23-C22F-4B22-9D72-790E84F6070E/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "pt-br"; #Portugese (Brazil)
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/E/F/0EF8F011-89A6-43AE-BD52-090918750432/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "pt-pt"; #Portugese (Portugal)
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/8/0/880A4C0E-25CA-43B5-84EF-A788FA462AB2/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "ro"; #Romanian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/D/26D339A3-0304-4B66-8062-98BDC0E0D413/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "ru"; #Russian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/D/2/FD2B1BA8-9841-46F9-A4A7-B97294554249/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "sr-sp"; #Serbian (Latin)
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/E/7/0E7A8426-7797-48F9-B396-AA96ADD1D899/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "sk"; #Slovak
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/3/5/035FD96F-04B1-4461-B8E9-6492654C8549/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "sl"; #Slovenian
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/D/5/0D547EA0-C094-4D06-BE15-F5111A1D4642/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "es-mx" #Spanish
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/9/5296BCC9-F0ED-461F-9E22-8A816DEC75C8/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "sv-se"; #Swedish
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/E/A/EEA4DC8B-4979-44C5-AF5E-E326DA04661C/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "th"; #Thai
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/1/1/2118AF0D-A747-486E-A5BB-6B35E5588247/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "tr"; #Turkish
            "http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/9/D/59DEC052-7E29-4F40-A27A-9AA94A8AAA1A/ServerLanguagePack.exe" = "uk" #Ukranian
            }
ForEach ($Url in $UrlList.Keys)
{
    $languageCode = $UrlList[$Url]

    $DestFileName = $Url.Split('/')[-1]
    Try
    {
        $LanguageDestFolder = "$DestFolder\$languageCode"
        New-Item -ItemType Directory $LanguageDestFolder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        ## Check if destination file already exists
        If (!(Test-Path "$LanguageDestFolder\$DestFileName"))
        {
            ## Begin download
            Start-BitsTransfer -Source $Url -Destination $LanguageDestFolder\$DestFileName -DisplayName "Downloading `'$DestFileName`' to $LanguageDestFolder" -Priority High -Description "From $Url..." -ErrorVariable err
            If ($err) {Throw ""}
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Host " - File $DestFileName already exists, skipping..."
        }
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Warning " - An error occurred downloading `'$DestFileName`'"
        break
    }
}
## View the downloaded files in Windows Explorer
Invoke-Item $DestFolder
## Pause
Write-Host "- Downloads completed, press any key to exit..."
$null = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```